# loading data using the plugin data dataLoader,amcharts (Uncaught TypeError:Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, amcharts

I'm trying to load data using dataLoader to build the chart (Amcharts) 
and for that i'm calling a method from controller(APS.NET MVC web application) that return a JSON data, the data contain a **date** and i think this is causing the problem

this is the method that return JSON:

```
 [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult DataStatSum()
    {
        string dossier = Session["Dossier"].ToString();  
        string societe = Session["Societe"].ToString(); 
        int userId = Int32.Parse(Session["USER_ID"].ToString());

        List<Report_DrillDownSum_Result> l = db.Report_DrillDownSum(dossier,societe, 62, 353, 354).ToList();
        var jsonn = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(l);
        var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(l);
        return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

and this is javascript code (chart configuration):

```
 <script src="~/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/amchratsV3.17.2/amcharts/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/amchratsV3.17.2/amcharts/serial.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/amchratsV3.17.2/amcharts/plugins/dataloader/dataloader.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/amchratsV3.17.2/amcharts/themes/light.js"></script>
@*<script src="~/js/date.format.js"></script>*@

<script type="text/javascript">
    AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv",
       {
           "type": "serial",
           "dataLoader":
           {
               "url": "/ChartStat/DataStatSum",
               "format": "json"
           },
           "categoryField": "JourD",
           "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD",
           "angle": 30,
           "depth3D": 30,
           "startDuration": 1,
           "fontSize": 14,
           "handDrawn": true,
           "handDrawScatter": 4,
           "theme": "light",
           "categoryAxis": {
               "gridPosition": "start",
               "parseDates": true
           },
           "trendLines": [],
           "graphs": [
               {
                   "balloonText": "[[title]] : [[value]] km",
                   "fillAlphas": 1,
                   "id": "AmGraph-1",
                   "title": "Athlete 1",
                   "type": "column",
                   "valueField": "ValDim1"
               },
               {
                   "balloonText": "[[title]] : [[value]] km",
                   "fillAlphas": 1,
                   "id": "AmGraph-2",
                   "title": "Athlete 2",
                   "type": "column",
                   "valueField": "ValDim2"
               }
           ],
           "guides": [],
           "valueAxes": [
               {
                   "id": "ValueAxis-1",
                   //   "title": "Axis title"
               }
           ],
           "allLabels": [],
           "balloon": {},
           "legend": {
               "useGraphSettings": true
           },
           "titles": [
               {
                   "id": "Title-1",
                   "size": 15,
                   "text": "Distance parcourue (km)"
               }
           ],

       })
```

actually i get the error when i put "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD" .

JSON data looks like :

```
"[{\"JourD\":\"2015-09-01\",\"ValDim1\":17126.0,\"ValDim2\":18080.0},{\"JourD\":\"2015-09-08\",\"ValDim1\":16960.0,\"ValDim2\":18000.0},{\"JourD\":\"2015-09-15\",\"ValDim1\":17880.0,\"ValDim2\":18075.0}]"
```

i get this error in google chrome console when i try to display the chart:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined.

---

**changing** my method to this solve the problem, cause i dont need to convert the object to JSON string

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult DataStatSum()
{
    string dossier = Session["Dossier"].ToString();  
    string societe = Session["Societe"].ToString(); 
    int userId = Int32.Parse(Session["USER_ID"].ToString());

    List<Report_DrillDownSum_Result> l = db.Report_DrillDownSum(dossier,societe, 62, 353, 354).ToList();
     return Json(l, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

Comment: Your JSON does not look right. It's an escaped stringified JSON. JSON must not be a string, but rather a JavaScript. I.e.: `[{"JourD":"2015-09-01","ValDim1":17126.0,"ValDim2":18080.0},{"JourD":"2015-09-08","ValDim1":16960.0,"ValDim2":18000.0},{"JourD":"2015-09-15","ValDim1":17880.0,"ValDim2":18075.0}]`

Comment: yes,  `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(l)`converts the object to a JSON string, then  `Json(object, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)` will not  serialzes it correctly  to JSON. so i have to pass my object directly  like this : `Json(l, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)` thank you !!

Comment: OK, so `/ChartStat/DataStatSum` URL returns serialized JSON or not? It should return un-serialized JSON for Data Loader to work properly.